# How to enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Undertow?

Tags: java, angularjs, cors, undertow

Try 1

```
builder.setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(new HttpString("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"), "*");
                    exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(new HttpString("Access-Control-Allow-Methods"),
                            "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
                    String ss = exchange.getResponseHeaders().get(new HttpString("Access-Control-Allow-Headers"))
                            .getFirst();
                    System.out.println(ss);
                    exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(new HttpString("Access-Control-Allow-Headers"), ss);
                }
            });
```

Try 2

```
HttpHandler enHandler = new SetHeaderHandler("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
builder.setHandler(enHandler);
```

I tried this above settings to enable the CORS in my undertow service, but it not working with my angular UI. works fine in postman.

Comment: When you say not working, what do you mean exactly? Can you tell us what headers go in the request, and what headers come back in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works after adding these line

```
        ResteasyDeployment rd = new ResteasyDeployment();
        CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter();
        filter.setAllowedMethods("GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        filter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
        rd.setProviderFactory(new ResteasyProviderFactory());
        rd.getProviderFactory().register(filter);
```

Comment: This is the way to go if you want CORS on a servlet deployment but no use if you want any HttpHandler like a File handler for example

Comment: This is RESTEasy (JAX-RS) specific, not a universal answer to the question as posed. P.S.: a more JAX-RS implementation agnostic way to register the CorsFilter is by creating a `@Provider` that `implements Feature`. But the CorsFilter itself is still RESTEasy specific.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently had the same issue with the Undertow server's ability to add the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header.

Although not very convenient, I was able to set the header inside of the **HttpHandler.handleRequest** method as such:

```
httpServerExchange.getResponseHeaders()
                .put(new HttpString("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"), "*");
```

As described in [UNDERTOW-1376](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-1376), the Undertow community seems to suggest using either [undertow-cors-filter](https://github.com/Download/undertow-cors-filter) or [cors-filter](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html) as community developed solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When protected resources are accessed by unauthenticated request, Servlet based filters will not have a chance to intercept such requests for sending CORS headers. So, any servlet based filters may not be suitable for such requirements.

Also, the undertow-cors-filter seems to be not updated and not working (when I tried with Wildfly 15). Its failing with regex related errors.

CORS Filter functionality could be achieved in Wildfly using Undertow Predicates & Exchange Attributes. A regex can be used to define the list of domains to be whitelisted. And the CORS related response headers could be written conditionally by checking the incoming Origin header and comparing it against the whitelist using regex matching. All these could be configured in the standalone.xml of Wildfly without any Java coding. The following article explains the same.

https://medium.com/amritatech/a-mechanism-to-enable-cors-filter-with-no-coding-57ef2906e023